# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model_...::function() on controller -Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got the message Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model_...::function()
but its just happened on 1 function

so here's my code

Controller :

```
function paidgen(){
  $reportcode=$this->input->get('paid');


    $data = array(
        'status' => 'Proccess'
    );

  $getcode= $this->model_expreport->changestat($data,$reportcode);
   $data['getcode2'] = $getcode;

   $this->loadpage($data);

}

function loadpage($data){
  parent::header();
$this->load->view('reportlands',$data);

  parent::footer();
}
```

View :

```
<input name="paid[]" value="<?php echo $o->reportcode ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkpaid" />
<span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>

 <form method="get" action="<?php echo site_url()? >cexpreport/paidgen" class="pull-right">  
  <input name="paid[]" value="<?php echo $o->reportcode ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkpaid" /></form>
```

i separate input checkbox with form with javascript but i think that's not the problem, because another code work as well

Model :

```
 function changestat($data,$reportcode){
 $this->db->where('reportcode', $reportcode);
$this->db->update('expreport', $data);
 }
```

Hope you can give me suggestions ,Thank you very much

Comment: Did you load the model in your controller before the model function call ?

Comment: Please add the full error mesage

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model_expreport::changestat() in D:\App\xampp\htdocs\expense\application\controllers\cexpreport.php on line 40

Comment: Solved guys ,,xD Thanks for ur answers, its my funny fault , my fault is just because i put "}" in the different function